# Escaping special characters in wildcard search using Lucene.NET

Tags: search, lucene, escaping, wildcard, lucene.net

I have looked for a long time for escaping special characters like *#, {, , [, ], ...* while in wildcard search in Lucene.NET 3.0.3.0, but I can´t find any possible solutions.

I have index my documents using *StandardAnalyzer*. The field *"title"* has the attributs *Field.Store.YES* and *Field.Index.ANALYZED*.
While searching I called MultiFieldQueryParser.Escape for my searchterm. The escaped query looks right but parsing the term remove the escaping characters. So my search can not find any results.

searchterm: `Klammer[affe]`
escaped searchterm: `*Klammer\\[affe\\]*`
after parsing: `title:*Klammer[affe]*`

So, how can I escape special characters in wildcard-Search?

Comment: I have no confidence I am looking at what you actually intended.  Can you please lose the italics, and enclose code elements (especially your search terms, etc) [in backticks (\`)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?  Looking at `*title:*Klammer[affe]**`, I have no idea which are supposed to be italics, and which are supposed to be actual asterisks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to index and search phrase query with special characters in lucene.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610067/how-to-index-and-search-phrase-query-with-special-characters-in-lucene-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [lucene documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters)

> **Escaping Special Characters**
>
> Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query
>   syntax. The current list special characters are
>
> ```
> + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
> ```
>
> To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example
>   to search for (1+1):2 use the query:
>
> `\(1\+1\)\:2`

So your query should be `*Klammer\[affe\]*`

But the standard analyzer deletes those characters so you need to index the original content differently.

See this related questions answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628127/956658. Another question with some info on changing the analyzing method [How to perform a lucene query containing special character using QueryParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839053/how-to-perform-a-lucene-query-containing-special-character-using-queryparser)

Comment: Don't forget that starting from Lucene 4.0 "/" is also a special character (used in regex).

Answer (score 20):

You could also use the Lucene implementation `QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery)`.

Comment: Great suggestion. Use the built in implementation. Avoid writing this code + unit tests yourself.